# Having trouble parsing a txt file into a list full of zip codes in my zipcode lookup program

Tags: python

Hello everyone thanks for looking into my problem.  What I am trying to do is write a "Structured" program in python that takes txt from a file and parses it into lists.  Then after closing the file, I need to reference the user input (zipcode) in those lists and then print out the city and state according to the zipcode that they entered.  My instructor is having us use structure by making several functions.  I know there are probably lots of more efficient ways of doing this, but I must keep the structure thats in place.
**EDIT**
Here is my code(Current):

```
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------
# VARIABLE DEFINITIONS

eof = False
zipRecord = ""
zipFile = ""
zipCode = []
city = []
state = []
parsedList = []

#-----------------------------------------------------------------------
# CONSTANT DEFINITIONS

USERPROMPT = "\nEnter a zip code to find (Press Enter key alone to stop): "

#-----------------------------------------------------------------------
# FUNCTION DEFINITIONS

def startUp():
    global zipFile
    print "zipcode lookup program".upper()
    zipFile = open("zipcodes.txt","r")
    loadList()

def loadList():
    while readRecord():
        pass
    processRecords()


def readRecord():
    global eof, zipList, zipCode, city, state, parsedList
    zipRecord = zipFile.readline()
    if zipRecord == "":
        eof = True
    else:
        parsedList = zipRecord.split(",")
        zipCode.append(parsedList[0])
        city.append(parsedList[1])
        state.append(parsedList[2])
        eof = False
    return not eof

def processRecords():
        userInput = raw_input(USERPROMPT)
        if userInput:
            print userInput
            print zipCode
            if userInput in zipCode:
                index_ = zipcode.index(userInput) 
                print "The city is %s and the state is %s " % \
                      (city[index_], state[index_])
            else:
                print "\nThe zip code does not exist."
        else:
            print "Please enter a data"

def closeUp():
    zipFile.close()

#-----------------------------------------------------------------------
# PROGRAM'S MAIN LOGIC

startUp()
closeUp()

raw_input("\nRun complete. Press the Enter key to exit.")
```

Here is a sample from the zipcode txt file:

```
00501,HOLTSVILLE,NY
```

I am definitely stuck at this point and would appreciate your help in this matter.
**EDIT**

Thanks for all the help everyone.  I really do appreciate it. :)

Comment: well to start it off this "AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'append'"

Comment: Idiomatic Python would have you put `if __name__ == "__main__":` in the program's main logic section.

Comment: What line? Post the entire error message (edit the question) and we'll be happy to help you fix it.

Comment: @eleven: surely you can fix that? The clue is in the error -- you can't `append` to strings. Use `foo += "some stuff"` instead.

Comment: zipCode, city and state variables are of type string, declare them to be lists if you want to use the append() method on them. Do not use `where` which is a reserved word in Python. I don't see a loop in the readRecord() method that iterates through the file of zip codes. Your code parses the first line only. Use `readlines()` instead: `for line in file.readlines(): listZip.append(line)`

Comment: thanks, I apologize for my n00bishness.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

why you fill the lists zipcode, city , state like that, i mean in each user entry we get the next line from the file

i think that you should do :

```
def loadList():
    # Fill all the list first , make the readRecord() return eof (True or False).
    while readRecord():
        pass

    # than process data (check for zip code) this will run it only one time
    # but you can put it in a loop to repeat the action.
    processRecords()
```

about your problem :

```
def processRecords():
        userInput = raw_input(USERPROMPT)
        # Check if a user has entered a text or not
        if userInput:
            # check the index from zipcode   

            if userInput in zipcode:
                # the index of the zipcode in the zipcode list is the same 
                # to get related cities and states.
                index_ = zipcode.index(userInput) 
                print "The city is %s and the state is %s " % \
                      (city[index_], state[index_])
            else:
                print "\nThe zip code does not exist."
        else:
            print "Please enter a data"
```

Comment: +1 Great! I was writing something similar, you beat me to it :)

Comment: thanks for the help.  For some reason, no matter what zip code I enter, I still get "The zip code does not exist" part of the else statement.

Comment: hmmm, try to __print zipcode__ and __print userInput__ before __if userInput in zipcode__  to see why, hope this will hekp you :)

Comment: 93308
['00501']
Yeah its only checking it against the first line.

Comment: it seem that __zipcode__ var wasn't filled , have you changed __loadList()__ like in my example if yes , and i see in your example that you didn't change __readRecord()__ like i told you have to add __return eof__ in the end of this function

Comment: Ok I added return eof to the end of my readRecord function and I am still getting the same results.  I'll update what my code looks like in my original post.

Comment: stupid i'm :) you should return __return not eof__ in your case, because you should continue reading the records until eof = True this is the mean of __while readRecord(): pass__

Comment: You aren't stupid. :) Thanks for helping me out.  I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

one of the beauties of Python is that it's interactive. if you take processRecords() out of loadList(), and then at the bottom of your program put:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
 processRecords()
```

Then, from the command prompt, type "python". You'll get the Python shell prompt, ">>>". There you type:

```
from zipcodes import * # this assumes your program is zipcodes.py
dir()  # shows you what's defined
print zipCode  # shows you what's in zipCode
```

that ought to help debugging.

Answer (score 0):

Strings don't have an `append` method like lists do. What I think you're trying to do is append the strings `zipCode`, `city`, and `state` to `parsedList`. This is the code you'd use to do that:

```
parsedList.append(zipCode)
parsedList.append(city)
parsedList.append(state)
```

Or, even more compactly:

```
parsedList = [zipCode, city, state]
```

Let me know if you get another error message and I can offer more suggestions.